# validating json string using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, json, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this json string `{"Table" : [{"subject" : "No Records are there to Display"}]}`.
If i receive this data i want to alert `NO Records Found`. Any suggestion.

**Note:** My key field may vary accordingly (ie) here it is `Subject` and some more like `Details`,`Description`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) or any other library to convert the JSON string into a JS object:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"Table" : [{"subject" : "No Records are there to Display"}]}');
if (obj.Table[0].subject === "No Records are there to Display") {
    alert("NO Records Found");
}
```

Comment: well the obj.Table is an array of json dictionary. Shouldn't this be as obj.Table[0].subject === "No Records are there to Display" ?